# Кодировка в Андроиде

Tags: android, кодировка, java

Приложение методом get получает информацию от удаленного сервера, но эта информация в windows-1251, и поэтому в приложении вместо букв отображаются ромбики со знаком вопрса внутри. Можно ли в приложении поменять кодировку, что бы не менять ее на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
String utf8String= new String(cp1251String.getBytes("Cp1251"), "UTF-8");
```

Взял [отсюда](http://gennadz.blogspot.com/2010/11/windows-cp1251-utf-8-java.html).

А [здесь](https://www.google.com/?q=java+cp1251+to+utf-8) Вы можете найти еще больше вариантов решения вашей проблемы.